Im trying to plot a Airfoil using matlab and want a sharp edge but i cant figure it out
% Parameters for the Kármán–Trefftz transformation
beta = .491; % Offset from the origin (adjust for trailing edge)
n = 4; % Increase for sharper features
b = -0.3; % Adjust for different airfoil characteristics

% Circle in the complex plane
theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100); % Angle for the circle
zeta = beta + exp(1i * theta); % Circle centered at (beta, 0) with radius 1

% Kármán–Trefftz transformation
z = (n*b*(zeta + b).^n + (zeta - b).^n) ./ ((zeta + b).^n - (zeta - b).^n);

% Create subplots to display both shapes
figure;

% Plot the circle
subplot(1, 2, 1);
plot(real(zeta), imag(zeta), 'b-');
axis equal; % Keep the aspect ratio equal
xlabel('Real Part');
ylabel('Imaginary Part');
title('Circle in the Complex Plane');
grid on;
% Set y-limits for both plots to be identical
ylim([-1.3 1.3]); % Adjust based on your needs
xlim([-1 1.9]); % Adjust based on your needs

% Plot the airfoil
subplot(1, 2, 2);
plot(real(z), imag(z), 'r-');
axis equal; % Keep the aspect ratio equal
xlabel('Real Part');
ylabel('Imaginary Part');
title('Airfoil Shape via Kármán–Trefftz Transformation');
grid on;

% Set y-limits for both plots to be identical
ylim([-.5 .5]); % Adjust based on your needs


I know the issues is with the formula for z but i dont how to get it to stop to create the sharp edge. the image is the the figure my code prints out.
I tried to change the beta,n,& b values which did help from bringing it looking like a egg to a airfoil without sharp edge. If I gove over n=4.999 its starts to cross over x axis.
